# HTML-валидатор

Tags: html

Подскажите нормальный валидатор для HTML.
А то пользуюсь этим:
[validome.org](http://www.validome.org).
Он даже не знает тегов galleryimg="false" на img и
color на hr. На них выдаёт, что это вообще не параметры этих тегов!

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://validator.w3.org
По поводу атрибута того что вы спрашивали, он уникальный для ие, и является атрибутом, который не соответствует стандартам.

Comment: Ага видел такой, принцип работы мне кажеться идентичен. (интервейс вывода уж точно). Просто уж очень они придирчивы допустим к закрытию через />

Comment: стандарт есть стандарт

Answer (score 2):

Пользуюсь встроенным в Sublime Text 3 плагином [SublimeLinter-html-tidy](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-html-tidy). Это удобно, поскольку ошибки и устаревшие привычки высвечиваются прямо во время написания кода. Как делал раньше: после того, как HTML-страница начинала функционировать, как от неё требовалось, копипастил код в [валидатор](http://validator.w3.org/) и обнаруживал множество однотипных ошибок, — приходилось массово редактировать собственные неточности. С использованием SublimeLinter-html-tidy все недочёты исправляю прямо на ходу, запоминая, как делать не следует.

Если в HTML-разметке обнаруживается какая-то ошибка, слева от номера строки появляется цветной кружок, а в Status Bar комментарии, как в валидаторе. Примеры:

[image: Саша в центре]
[image: Атрибут align]

Как видно, поддерживается спецификация HTML благодаря использованию Tidy-HTML5 — форка библиотеки [HTML-Tidy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy). В Windows 10 её компоненты не загружаются при помощи менеджеров пакетов, придётся устанавливать вручную.

1. [Устанавливаем через Package Control](http://forum.sublimetext.ru/index.php?topic=6.0) плагин [SublimeLinter3](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3).
2. Устанавливаем через Package Control плагин SublimeLinter-html-tidy.
3. Скачиваем [последнюю версию HTML Tidy](http://binaries.html-tidy.org/).
4. [Находим, где содержится переменная PATH](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml). Кликаем на лупу в левом нижнем углу около значка с окном → в поле с плейсхолдером *Поиск в Windows* вписываем *Система (Панель управления)* → кликаем на блок, появившийся под *Лучшее соответствие*:

[image: Система (Панель управления)]

<kbd>Дополнительные параметры системы</kbd> → <kbd>Переменные среды...</kbd> → кликаем по *PATH* → <kbd>Изменить...</kbd> → копируем путь, находящийся в поле напротив *Значение переменной:*. У меня это `C:\Users\СашаБожественна\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

[image: Саша Божественна]

5. В папку, путь к которой мы только что получили (для меня npm) копируем файлы *tidy.dll* и *tidy.exe* из архива с HTML Tidy → SublimeLinter-html-tidy должен заработать.

Об установке линтеров/валидаторов на Sublime Text 3 для других языков разметки/программирования см. в [**статье на Хабрахабре**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/262137/).