# Sublime text Autoprefixer ERROR

Tags: sublime-text

Вчера настроил по уроку WebDesign Master в Gulp autoprefixer... Вчера все работало, сегодня запускаю - выдает ошибку (((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
body
 background-color: #f00
 font-size: 18px
 min-width: 320px
 position: relative
```

Почему при отсутствии точки с запятой выадет ошибку, ежели SASS основан на то, что работает без этих символов???

Comment: Файл свой покажите. Вы смотрели, что там на линии 2, символе 13? Проверяли, где могли пропустить точку с запятой? Спасибо.

Comment: Вчера была прохожая проблема с запуском самого SASS в командной строке. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567663/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-sass В итоге выяснилось, что я отступы неверно делал... А тут окно выскакивает в самом Sublime

Comment: Линтерами пользуйтесь, они опечатки в синтаксисе показывают: см. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548376/199934 и https://habrahabr.ru/post/262137/ .

Comment: Интересно, что у автора видеоурока тоже нет ; но у него все работает (( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW51JUVT66w см. на 13:36:46

Comment: Не длится то видео 13 часов)) . Возможно, у Вас синтаксис SCSS, где нужны точки с запятой, а у автора ролика Sass?

Comment: Удобнее, если ссылки на YouTube с привязкой ко времени даются. Останавливаете ролик на секунде, с которой желаете показать, → правой кнопкой мыши по видео → *Копировать URL видео с привязкой ко времени* → вставляете полученную ссылку.

Comment: https://youtu.be/vW51JUVT66w?t=6069